# GridView cannot be cast to ViewPager in Kotlin Custom Calendar

Tags: kotlin, gridview, android-viewpager, classcastexception, calendarview

Working on the custom calendar in Kotlin.

On tapping the DateText, this custom calendar widget will be opened in a new fragment.

I used Grid Views to display the dates and I'm getting ClassCastException on navigating to the Calendar Screen(GridView cannot be cast to ViewPager).

Error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.daimler.myfinance.payment.paymentdate.extensions.CalendarGridView cannot be cast to com.daimler.myfinance.payment.paymentdate.extensions.CalendarViewPager
at com.payment.paymentdate.CalendarView.initUiElements(CalendarView.kt)
```

CalendarView.kt

```
open class CalendarView : LinearLayout {
   private var mViewPager: CalendarViewPager? = null

   private fun initUiElements() {
        
        mViewPager =  findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.calendarViewPager) as CalendarViewPager
    }
}
```

CalendarViewPager.kt

```
class CalendarViewPager : ViewPager {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {

    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) :  super(context!!, attrs) {

    }
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        var heightMeasureSpec = heightMeasureSpec
        var height = 0
        for (i in 0 until getChildCount()) {
            val child: View = getChildAt(i)
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))
            val h = child.measuredHeight
            if (h > height) {
                height = h
            }
        }
        if (height != 0) {
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    }
}
```

calendar_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- date toolbar -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendarHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/jumio_white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/abbreviationsBar">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/previousButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_left"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.uikit.widgets.textviews.MBBody2TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentDateLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/jumio_black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/previousButton"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/forwardButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="April 2020" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/forwardButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- eventDays header -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/abbreviationsBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calendarHeader">

        <com.\uikit.widgets.textviews.MBBody2TextView
            android:id="@+id/mondayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/material_calendar_monday"
            android:textColor="@color/jumio_black" />

        <com.uikit.widgets.textviews.MBBody2TextView
            android:id="@+id/tuesdayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/material_calendar_tuesday"
            android:textColor="@color/jumio_black" />

        <com.uikit.widgets.textviews.MBBody2TextView
            android:id="@+id/wednesdayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/material_calendar_wednesday"
            android:textColor="@color/jumio_black" />

        <com.uikit.widgets.textviews.MBBody2TextView
            android:id="@+id/thursdayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/material_calendar_thursday"
            android:textColor="@color/jumio_black" />

        <com.uikit.widgets.textviews.MBBody2TextView
            android:id="@+id/fridayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/material_calendar_friday"
            android:textColor="@color/jumio_black" />

        <com.uikit.widgets.textviews.MBBody2TextView
            android:id="@+id/saturdayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/material_calendar_saturday"
            android:textColor="@color/jumio_black" />

        <com.uikit.widgets.textviews.MBBody2TextView
            android:id="@+id/sundayLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/material_calendar_sunday"
            android:textColor="@color/jumio_black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridScroll"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/abbreviationsBar">

        <com.payment.paymentdate.extensions.CalendarGridView
            android:id="@+id/calendarViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your xml you have defined `com.payment.paymentdate.extensions.CalendarGridView` which is subclassof GridView and you are assigning it to ViewPager wich is type of `ViewPager`

```
<com.payment.paymentdate.extensions.CalendarViewPager
            android:id="@+id/calendarViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear idea. Then how do I achieve populating dates in calendar? What modifications should be done? Please let me know.